# My CSS affected my whole page instead of just the defined text

Tags: html, css

My web page was messed up my one bit of code that I added to the page. It was supposed to create a glitch y text box, but instead it affect the whole page. As far as I know, I have included all of the necessary <>'s that need to separate the code. What else may be the problem? I have not yet learned how to make the page reference a CSS page, so I just internalize the CSS with the  tag

```
<p data-text="PSYCHO">


PSYCHO

<style>
//@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:800');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade');

:root {
  --f-size: 15;
  --f-unit: 1vmin;
  --f: calc(var(--f-size) * var(--f-unit));
  --bg: #181717; 
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bungee Shade', cursive;//'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--f);

  background-color: var(--bg);
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  flex: 1;
  line-height: .75;
  margin: auto;
  color: #1af0dc;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleX(var(--scale, 1));
  animation: glitch-p 11s infinite alternate;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    --top: 0;        // offset from top [0 - 10]
    --left: 0;       // offset from left [0.001 - 1]
    --v-height: 30%; // visible part

    --n-tenth: calc(var(--f-size) * .1 * var(--top));
    --t-cut: calc(var(--n-tenth) / var(--f-size) * 100%);
    --b-cut: calc(var(--t-cut) + var(--v-height));

    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;

    transform: translateX(calc(var(--left) * 100%));

    // this helps to get rid of pixelization
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 transparent); 

    text-shadow: calc(var(--left) * -3em) 0 .02em lime, 
                 calc(var(--left) * -6em) 0 .02em #ff00e1;

    background-color: var(--bg);
    clip-path: polygon(0% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--b-cut), 0% var(--b-cut));
  } 

  &::before {
    animation: glitch-b 1.7s infinite alternate-reverse;
  }
  &::after {
    animation: glitch-a 3.1s infinite alternate;
  }
}

@keyframes glitch-p {
  17% { --scale: .87; }
  31% { --scale: 1.1; }
  37% { --scale: 1.3; }
  47% { --scale: .91; }
  87% { --scale: 1; }
}

@keyframes glitch-a {
  10%,30%,50%,70%,90% {
    --top: 0;
    --left: 0;
  }
  0% {
   --v-height: 15%; 
  }
  20% {
    --left: .005;
  }
  40% {
    --left: .01;
    --v-height: 20%;
    --top: 3;
  }
  60% {
    --left: .03;
    --v-height: 25%;
    --top: 6;
  }
  80% {
    --left: .07;
    --v-height: 5%;
    --top: 8;
  }
  100% {
    --left: .083;
    --v-height: 30%;
    --top: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes glitch-b {
    10%,30%,50%,70%,90% {
    --top: 0;
    --left: 0;
  }
  0% {
   --v-height: 15%; 
   --top: 10;
  }
  20% {
    --left: -.005;
  }
  40% {
    --left: -.01;
    --v-height: 17%;
    --top: 3;
  }
  60% {
    --left: -.03;
    --v-height: 35%;
    --top: 6;
  }
  80% {
    --left: -.07;
    --v-height: 5%;
    --top: 8;
  }
  100% {
    --left: -.083;
    --v-height: 30%;
    --top: 1;
  }
}
</style>
</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but `style` elements are not scoped to their containing elements...

Answer (score 4):

```
p {
  &::before {
    ...
  }
}
```

is `scss` syntax. (The nesting of selectors). To use `scss` you will need `sass` to transpile your `scss` to `css` first.

If you want to do it in plain `css` you will need to specify the full tags, always.

```
p {
  ...
}

p::before {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you include the CSS code in the page, you have to put in the head of the document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page title</title>
  <style>
   /* YOUR STYLE GOES HERE */
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- page content -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Then you can style your `<p>` giving it a class or a unique id (something like `<p id="myFancyText"></p>`) and pointing at it in CSS code with the selector `#myFancyText`.
In this way the CSS code will affect only your selected element and not all the document.

Also, I noticed you used SCSS syntax (`&::before` and similar) that won't work without being transpiled into plain CSS.

Hope this helps!

PS: to link an external CSS file, just put a link in the `head` of the document, pointing at the file. (Pay attention to the path of the folder you put the file!)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/style.css">
```

Comment: You don't **have** to put it in the `head` element, it's just good practice. You can put it in `div` if you want. I've done it for testing on the fly in developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see your snippet impacting your entire web page is the fact that you're using element based styling instead of class based. Try swapping out the `p { ... }` for `.glitchy-p { ... }` and assigning your element that class:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Bungee Shade', cursive;//'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--f);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.glitchy-p {
  flex: 1;
  line-height: .75;
  margin: auto;
  color: #1af0dc;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleX(var(--scale, 1));
  animation: glitch-p 11s infinite alternate;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    --top: 0;        // offset from top [0 - 10]
    --left: 0;       // offset from left [0.001 - 1]
    --v-height: 30%; // visible part

    --n-tenth: calc(var(--f-size) * .1 * var(--top));
    --t-cut: calc(var(--n-tenth) / var(--f-size) * 100%);
    --b-cut: calc(var(--t-cut) + var(--v-height));

    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;

    transform: translateX(calc(var(--left) * 100%));

    // this helps to get rid of pixelization
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 transparent); 

    text-shadow: calc(var(--left) * -3em) 0 .02em lime, 
                 calc(var(--left) * -6em) 0 .02em #ff00e1;

    background-color: var(--bg);
    clip-path: polygon(0% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--t-cut), 100% var(--b-cut), 0% var(--b-cut));
  } 

  &::before {
    animation: glitch-b 1.7s infinite alternate-reverse;
  }
  &::after {
    animation: glitch-a 3.1s infinite alternate;
  }
}

@keyframes glitch-p {
  17% { --scale: .87; }
  31% { --scale: 1.1; }
  37% { --scale: 1.3; }
  47% { --scale: .91; }
  87% { --scale: 1; }
}

@keyframes glitch-a {
  10%,30%,50%,70%,90% {
    --top: 0;
    --left: 0;
  }
  0% {
   --v-height: 15%; 
  }
  20% {
    --left: .005;
  }
  40% {
    --left: .01;
    --v-height: 20%;
    --top: 3;
  }
  60% {
    --left: .03;
    --v-height: 25%;
    --top: 6;
  }
  80% {
    --left: .07;
    --v-height: 5%;
    --top: 8;
  }
  100% {
    --left: .083;
    --v-height: 30%;
    --top: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes glitch-b {
    10%,30%,50%,70%,90% {
    --top: 0;
    --left: 0;
  }
  0% {
   --v-height: 15%; 
   --top: 10;
  }
  20% {
    --left: -.005;
  }
  40% {
    --left: -.01;
    --v-height: 17%;
    --top: 3;
  }
  60% {
    --left: -.03;
    --v-height: 35%;
    --top: 6;
  }
  80% {
    --left: -.07;
    --v-height: 5%;
    --top: 8;
  }
  100% {
    --left: -.083;
    --v-height: 30%;
    --top: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p data-text="NOT PSYCHO">NOT PSYCHO</p>
<p data-text="PSYCHO" class="glitchy-p">PSYCHO</p>
```

This will ensure that only the elements that utilize the class `glitchy-p` will receive that styling as demonstrated above.

Answer (score -1):

Comments in plain CSS are `/* comment */`, and not `// comment`

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. I fail to see how this is useful to the OP in resolving why their `SCSS` would impact their entire web page.